# Responsive div's floating and centered

Tags: html, css, centering

Now I have put float:left on my green divs but that makes them stick to the left (makes sense). Now how can I keep my divs centered while I resize the blue container?

As in this image:

[image]

Blue: Parent container
Green: Divs

Comment: use inline-block or inline-table instead float and text-align on parent ...

Comment: Post your code, maybe even make a fiddle. P.S.: *Blue: Parent container Green: Divs* – u don't say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `display: inline-block` on your child items and `text-align: center` on parent item

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
    background-color: blue;
    width:500px;
    text-align: center;
}

.item {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g3vp2fyf/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
```

instead of

```
float: left;
```